# Closed-form derivative of a matrix function

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Let $A$ be an Hurwitz stable matrix (that is, the real part of the eigenvalues of $A$ is strictly negative) and $Q$ be a positive semidefinite matrix ($Q\ge 0$, for short). Let $P$ denote the solution of the following Lyapunov equation
$$
AP+PA^\top = -Q.
$$
Consider the following function of $Q$
$$
f(Q):=-\mathrm{tr}(Q(I+P)^{-1}),
$$
where $\mathrm{tr}(\cdot)$ denotes the matrix trace.

> **My questions:**
>
> 1. Is $f(Q)$ a convex function of $Q\ge 0$?
> 2. Does there exist a closed-form expression for the derivative $\displaystyle\frac{\partial f(Q)}{\partial Q}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vectorize the Lyapunov equation 
$$\eqalign{
 q &= -(A\otimes I+I\otimes A)\,p = -B^Tp \cr
}$$
Use a colon to denote the trace/Frobenius product
$$X:Y={\rm tr}(X^TY)$$
and define some new variables
$$\eqalign{
M &= (I+P) \,\,\,\implies\, dM=dP \cr
v &= {\rm vec}(M^{-T}Q^TM^{-T}) \cr
w &= {\rm vec}(M^{-T}) \cr\cr
}$$
Now find the differential and gradient of the function.
$$\eqalign{
 f &= -Q^T:M^{-1} \cr
df
 &= -Q^T:dM^{-1} - dQ^T:M^{-1} \cr
 &= Q^T:M^{-1}\,dP\,M^{-1} - M^{-T}:dQ \cr
 &= M^{-T}Q^TM^{-T}:dP - M^{-T}:dQ \cr
 &= {\rm vec}(M^{-T}Q^TM^{-T}):dp - {\rm vec}(M^{-T}):dq \cr
 &= v:dp - w:dq \cr
 &= -v:B^{-T}\,dq - w:dq \cr
 &= -(B^{-1}v + w):dq \cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial q} &= -(w+B^{-1}v) \cr
}$$
De-vectorize (matricize?) this to recover a matrix-valued gradient
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial f}{\partial Q}
 &= -{\rm Mat}\big(w+B^{-1}v\big) \cr
 &= -(I+P^T)^{-1}-{\rm Mat}\Big(\big(A^T\otimes I+I\otimes A^T\big)^{-1}{\rm vec}\big((I+P^T)^{-1}Q^T(I+P^T)^{-1}\big)\Big) \cr
}$$